# My Get Build Services support for .net core 6

Tags: .net-6.0, myget

Is there an item on the roadmap for MyGet build services to support net core 6?

Since I upgraded my solution to .net core 6, I am getting the following error message:

> C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'c:\temp\958d888\source...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net60' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

Looking at the official documentation, build services only support up .net core 3.1:

> **Build services supports the following frameworks and SDKs:**
> .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5 Development Tools, 4.0, 4.0 Targeting Pack (TP), 4.5, 4.5 TP, 4.5.1, 4.5.1 TP, 4.5.2, 4.5.2 TP, 4.6, 4.6 TP, 4.6.1, 4.6.1 SDK, 4.6.1 TP, 4.6.2, 4.6.2 SDK, 4.6.2 TP, 4.7, 4.7 SDK, 4.7 TP, 4.7.1 TP, 4.7.2 SDK, 4.7.2 TP, 4.8 SDK, 4.8 TP
> **.NET Core 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.14, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.202, 2.1.805, 2.2.207, 2.2.402, 3.0.103, 3.1.201**